# Data accuracy issue while extracting digits from cropped image using OCR/Pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I have some small images cropped from a report. While extracting the digits from the image, the extracted OCR data is very inconsistent. Below is the OCR config used

> pytesseract_custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 --dpi 300 -c
> tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'

I have tried the below items to  improve the data accuracy

1. Resized Image and OCR
2. Greyscaled
3. Upsampling and tresholding

But the data accuracy hasn't improved. I have written the code to write the extracted output as html for easy debugging

> Plaese check the methods extract_ocr_text & extract_ocr_text1 for extraction types

[image]

Few Cropped Samples

[image][image][image]
[image] [image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from os import listdir
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage
import re
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import uuid
import datetime

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

base_dir ="C:/Projects/Python/rico-nlp-python/TESTING"
folder_dir_image_cropped = base_dir + "/image_cropped"
folder_dir_cropped_resized = base_dir + "/cropped_resized"
debug_html_response = base_dir + "/debug_html_response"

enable_debug=True
cropped_image_resize_wh = (90, 120)
pytesseract_custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 --dpi 300 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'

def aspect_ratio(cnt):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    ratio = float(w)/h
    return ratio

def extract_ocr_text(imageIndex, imageDir, imageName):
    imagePath = imageDir + "/" + imageName

    image = Image.open(imagePath)
    grayscale_image = image.convert('L')

    # Perform OCR using PyTesseract
    extracted_text = image_to_string(
        grayscale_image, config=pytesseract_custom_config)

    # Extract numbers from the extracted text
    # numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', extracted_text)

    # Convert extracted number strings to numeric values
    # numeric_values = [int(number) for number in numbers]

    print(imageName, extracted_text, "=>", imageIndex)
    if(enable_debug):
        debugVerify(imageName, imagePath, extracted_text, (imageIndex+1))

def extract_ocr_text1(imageIndex, imageDir, imageName):
    imagePath = imageDir + "/" + imageName

    img1 = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gry1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (h, w) = gry1.shape[:2]
    gry1 = cv2.resize(gry1, (w*2, h*2))
    thr1 = cv2.threshold(gry1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    txt1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr1, config="digits")
    print("".join(t for t in txt1 if t.isalnum()))
    #cv2.imshow("thr1", thr1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    if(enable_debug):
        debugVerify(imageName, imagePath, txt1, (imageIndex+1))
 
def debugVerify(imageName, imagePath, extracted_text, imageIndex):
    if(imageIndex == 1):
        if(os.path.exists(debugFile)):
            os.remove(debugFile)

    with open(debugFile, 'a') as file:
        if(imageIndex == 1):
            file.write(
                '<html><body><table style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;"><tr colspan="4"><td>'+ title +'</td></tr>')

        file.write('<tr  style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px;"><td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px">' + str(imageIndex) + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px">' + imageName + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px"><img src="' + imagePath +'"></td><td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px;font-size:40px;font-weight: bold">' + extracted_text + '</td></tr>')

        if(imageIndex == ocr_image_files_length):
            file.write('</table></body></html>')

def resize_image(imageName):
    imagePath = folder_dir_image_cropped + "/" + imageName
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, tuple(
        cropped_image_resize_wh), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imwrite(folder_dir_cropped_resized + "/" + imageName, resized_image)

def smoothen_image(imageName):
    # Load the image in grayscale
    image = cv2.imread( folder_dir_cropped_resized +"/" + imageName, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Apply Gaussian blur for noise reduction
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)

    # Apply adaptive thresholding
    thresholded = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

    # Apply morphological operations (dilation and erosion)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
    morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresholded, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    # Find contours and isolate digit components
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in contours:
        # Extract and process each digit component
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        digit = morphed[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        cv2.imshow("Smoothened", digit) # Show it
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        # Apply further processing to each digit if needed
        # OCR can be applied to each digit afterwards


    if(imageIndex == 1):
        if(os.path.exists(debugFile)):
            os.remove(debugFile)

    with open(debugFile, 'a') as file:
        if(imageIndex == 1):
            file.write(
                '<html><body><table style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;">')

        file.write('<tr  style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px;"><td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px">' + imageName + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px"><img src="' + folder_dir_cropped_resized +
                   "/" + imageName + '"></td><td style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px;font-size:40px;font-weight: bold">' + extracted_text + '</td></tr>')

        if(imageIndex == ocr_image_files_length):
            file.write('</table></body></html>')

    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.remove(file_path)
                print(f"Deleted: {file_path}")
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                delete_files_in_directory(file_path)  # Recursive call for subdirectories
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error deleting {file_path}: {e}")
            
ocr_image_files_length = len(os.listdir(folder_dir_cropped_resized))

for imageName in os.listdir(folder_dir_image_cropped):
    resize_image(imageName)

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%f")[:-3]
debugFile = debug_html_response+ f'{current_time}__cropped.html'
title="<h1>CROPPED</h1>"

for imageIndex, imageName in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_dir_image_cropped)):
    extract_ocr_text(imageIndex, folder_dir_image_cropped, imageName)

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%f")[:-3]
debugFile = debug_html_response+ f'{current_time}__resized.html'
title="<h1>CROPPED Resized</h1>"

for imageIndex, imageName in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_dir_cropped_resized)):
    extract_ocr_text(imageIndex, folder_dir_cropped_resized, imageName)

# for imageIndex, imageName in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_dir_cropped_resized)):
#     smoothen_image(imageName)
```